# How can I execute a XSS on 302 redirect and the body on the page?

Tags: xss, javascript

Is there a way to execute XSS? on 302 redirect and the body on the page?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>302 Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://Example.com/">here</A>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I can breakout with `"` but i can't use any character after `<` or whole parameter would be removed.
Maybe there is a workaround to "stop" the redirect and show HTML? I'm almost 99.99% sure there is a way to break it somehow.

Comment: I don't think that the browser renders the body at all on a proper redirect (i.e. status code 302 and Location header). The body is only their for the unusual case of very old clients which don't know what 302 means - i.e. irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases a 302 redirect will not contain a body at all.

The [RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059662/http-302-redirect-is-a-message-body-needed#8059718) only requires a header to indicate the status 302 and the location the user should be redirected to.

As Steffen said, modern browsers ignore the body of the redirect and directly issue a GET for the location specified in the header.